# SizedBox.shrink() or Container() not returning empty Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using List.generate() to create a list of emojis for each category from a JSON object. I have a search bar that is used to narrow down the search results. If one of the emoji keywords contains the characters in the search bar it should only display that emoji.

The problem is SizedBox.shrink() is not empty like I want it to be.
Isn't SizedBox.shrink() the recommended way to return an empty widget?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

```
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (change) {
                    setState(() {
                      searchTarget = change;
                    });
                  },
                  controller: searchController,
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Search for Icon..."),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 16,
                left: 16,
              ),
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: this.jsonData.keys.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: 16, top: (index == 0) ? 0 : 16),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            this.jsonData.keys.toList()[index],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GridView.count(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        crossAxisCount: 8,
                        children: List.generate(
                          this.jsonData[this.jsonData.keys.toList()[index]].length, (jndex) {

                          var emoji = this.jsonData[this.jsonData.keys.toList()[index]][jndex];

                          if (this.searchTarget.length > 0 || this.searchTarget != " "){
                            for (int i = 0; i < emoji['keywords'].length; i++){
                              if (emoji['keywords'][i].contains(this.searchTarget)){
                                return Text(
                                emoji['emoji'],
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                                );
                              }
                            }
                          }

                          return SizedBox.shrink();
                        }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: SizedBox.shrink() is already returning with an empty child but even so it is a widget so it would take as much space as if there an widget. are you trying to display only the founded emojis without that empty space?

Comment: I want the 5 emojis in the second image to display in order right below the category title text as if they were search results. The whitespace surrounding them in the second image should be gone. Thanks.

Comment: You can archive that by editing the GridView, making it's length equal to the founded emojis if there was a text in the search.

Comment: Doing this would only return (lets say 3 items were found) 3 blank spaces. If the found emojis happen to one of the first 3 items in their category then they would be displayed. Thanks.

Comment: I solved it. Instead of building the gridview directly I created a method that generated the list itself. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. Instead of building the grid view directly I created a method that generated the list itself.